# Custom ListView return wrong selected item after filter

Tags: android, listview, filter, onitemclicklistener, favorites

I've got this code :

ArretsFragment.java :

```
package activity;

public class ArretsFragment extends Fragment  {

ConnectionDetector cd;
// Log tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "https://open.tan.fr/ewp/arrets.json";
private List<Arrets> arretsList = new ArrayList<Arrets>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
private Menu menu;
private MenuInflater inflater;
HashMap<String, String> lieumap = new HashMap<String, String>();
EditText search;
Spfav sharedPreference;

ArrayList listArrets;

public ArretsFragment() {
}

public void filtrer() {
    // retourner la chaine saisie par l'utilisateur
    String name = search.getText().toString();
    // créer une nouvelle liste qui va contenir la résultat à afficher
  ArrayList listFoodNew = new ArrayList();

    for (Arrets food : arretsList) {
        // si le nom du food commence par la chaine saisie , ajouter-le !
        if (food.getArret().toLowerCase().toString().startsWith(name)) {
            listFoodNew.add(food);
        }
    }
    //vider la liste
    listView.setAdapter(null);
    // ajouter la nouvelle liste
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), listFoodNew));

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

    // movieList is an empty array at this point.
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), arretsList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    search = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search);
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            filtrer();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    // Showing progress dialog before making http request


    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Rechargement...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            arretsList.clear();

            JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {

                                    JSONObject obj = null;
                                    try {
                                        obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    Arrets arret = new Arrets();

                                    arret.setArret(obj.getString("libelle"));


                                    String lieu = obj.getString("codeLieu");

                                    arret.setLieu(lieu);

                                    JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("ligne");
                                    ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                    int ligne = genreArry.length();


                                    for (int v = 0; v < ligne; v++) {

                                        JSONObject nl = genreArry.getJSONObject(v);
                                        genre.add(nl.optString("numLigne").toString());

                                    }

                                    arret.setLigne(genre);

                                    // adding movie to movies array
                                    arretsList.add(arret);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        }
    });
    swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lieu);
            String text = textView.getText().toString();

            TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arret);
            String libelle = textView2.getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(ArretsFragment.this.getActivity(), TempsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("text", text);
            i.putExtra("libelle", libelle);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {

                ImageView button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
                sharedPreference = new Spfav();

                String tag = button.getTag().toString();
                if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("grey")) {
                    sharedPreference.addFavorite(getActivity(), arretsList.get(position));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ajouté au favoris !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    button.setTag("red");
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_red);
                } else {
                    sharedPreference.removeFavorite(getActivity(), arretsList.get(position));
                    button.setTag("grey");
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart_white);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Supprimé des favoris !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    listArrets = new ArrayList();

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = null;
                            try {
                                obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Arrets arret = new Arrets();
                            arret.setArret(obj.getString("libelle"));


                            String lieu = obj.getString("codeLieu");

                            arret.setLieu(lieu);


                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("ligne");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            int ligne = genreArry.length();


                            for (int v = 0; v < ligne; v++) {

                                JSONObject nl = genreArry.getJSONObject(v);

                                genre.add(nl.optString("numLigne").toString());


                            }


                            arret.setLigne(genre);
                            arretsList.add(arret);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }


    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_arrets, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

And Spfav.java :

```
package util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import model.Arrets;


public class Spfav {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PRODUCT_APP";
public static final String FAVORITES = "Product_Favorite";

public Spfav() {
    super();
}

// This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<Arrets> favorites) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    Editor editor;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = settings.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);

    editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);

    editor.commit();
}

public void addFavorite(Context context, Arrets product) {
    List<Arrets> favorites = getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites == null)
        favorites = new ArrayList<Arrets>();
    favorites.add(product);
    saveFavorites(context, favorites);
}

public void removeFavorite(Context context, Arrets product) {
    ArrayList<Arrets> favorites = getFavorites(context);
    if (favorites != null) {
        favorites.remove(product);
        saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Arrets> getFavorites(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences settings;
    List<Arrets> favorites;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Arrets[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
                Arrets[].class);

        favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        favorites = new ArrayList<Arrets>(favorites);
    } else
        return null;

    return (ArrayList<Arrets>) favorites;
}
}
```

I would like to know why, when I filter and when I longclick an item, it takes the item before the filter!

It would be very nice to get some help.

Comment: This happen only with the `OnItemLongClickListener` or also with `OnItemClickListener`? can you post your `CustomListAdapter.class`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `OnItemClickListener` replace this:

> ```
>    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lieu);
>    String text = textView.getText().toString();
>    TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.arret);
>    String libelle = textView2.getText().toString();
> ```

with this:

```
Arrets item = (Arrets) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

The same applies to your `OnItemLongClickListener`.

In short - get items form your adapter rather than form a `ListView` or `ArrayList` of objects.

Comment: I speak about OnItemLongClickListener ! :/

Comment: @PierreBertier The same applies to your `OnItemLongClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of work that the adapter really should handle for you.
Plus every time you change the listview contents, you're creating a new adapter.

Creating a new adapter each time is wasteful and in my opinion, it's better to let the adapter handle the data.

Try setting the adapter as a global variable and just updating its contents when you filter.

PseudoCode:

```
CustomListAdapter mAdapter

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

    // movieList is an empty array at this point.
    mAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), arretsList);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

...
}
```

Now your adapter can store arretsList and update it as needed.

Then create a custom method in your adapter to update the stored arraylist and call it from the filtrer like this:

```
mAdapter.update(listFoodNew);
```

The reason you're getting a problem with the wrong item is because (as mentioned above) **you've got TWO adapters in play**.

The global one you're calling in setOnItemLongClickListener like this:

```
arretsList.get(position)
```

is NOT the same as the new adapter you've created in filtrer

```
listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), listFoodNew));
```

So you've created two difference adapters with two different datasets. One filtered, one not.

Try this:

```
@Override
public void setOnItemLongClickListener(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //I think this is the data type your adapter uses.
    Arrets food = mAdapter.getItem(position);

    //Now check your color and fire your toast
}
```